# pandas join not lining up with the "on" parameter

Tags: pandas, join

I am trying to `join` two dataframes on their "Hour" column; one dataframe has the datetime and various advection parameters for each hour over an 11 year time period and the other dataframe is the average value for each of the 24 hours over 11 years. Note that **both** dataframes are missing the 4th hour due to sampler maintenance at that time, so it is normal.

However, when I `join` the two dataframes, the 5th hour is dropped and skipped in the right dataframe, and the 6th hour from the right dataframe is aligned with the 5th hour from the left dataframe. This discontinuity is repeated all the way to the 22nd hour on the left dataframe. On the 23rd hour of the left dataframe, the right dataframe contains all nans. This is repeated all the way through the new dataframe for each day. I am not sure what's wrong?

Here is my code:

```
#wr csv download link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G5jTtksxBIykm4cScqwkAztsmVrQaIDJ/view?usp=share_link
#df csv download link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c1RuBMJ3ORvxxhmKAga0kwfd4S_1fJ03/view?usp=share_link

import pandas as pd

wr = pd.read_csv('')
df = pd.read_csv('')

wr["date"] = wr["date"].astype("M8")
wr["Month"] = wr.date.dt.month
wr['Hour'] = wr.date.dt.hour

comb = wr.join(df, on='Hour', how='left', rsuffix = '_clim')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas join is not suitable for joining 'one to many' operations.

> DataFrame.join always uses other’s index but we can use any column in df. This method preserves the original DataFrame’s index in the result.

You can see this easily when doing the join 'wrong way around':

```
df.join(wr, on='Hour', how='left', rsuffix = '_clim')
```

You get only 24 rows.

ref: [Join Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

What you want to do in this case is use **merge**:

```
comb = pd.merge(df, wr, how='left', on = 'Hour')
```

For more see [merge documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)